# Issues with playing video from url android

Tags: android, video-streaming, media-player, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I have my app playing a video from my server. Each video has various resolution qualities with links to each resolution. But sometimes there are some wrong links in my server.

How can I know when my VideoView has gotten the wrong link so that I can switch to another link with another resolution quality of the same video. Which event, or exception can I catch?

Comment: what's your video extension which is stored on server.

Answer (score 1):

For your videoView, implement an onErrorListenor and in the onError method, re-initialize your video player with another resolution.

Something like this:

```
videoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {           
            // In here, call your code to re-initialize the video;
        }
    });
```